# SoapUI how to generate dynamically request password?

Tags: request, soapui, encode

I need to generate the password of the request dynamically, because I need to concatenate it with a timestamp and encode the result with SHA-256 to get the actual password.

Is there a way to generate that password to every request?

Where should the script be created to generate the password, and how  can it be added to the request or to a variable that is read in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You have full access to the Groovy language in SoapUI. You can do any sort of coding in a Groovy script test step. Then you can store the resulting value in a [property](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties/):

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("passwordVar", passwdResult)
```

And in the request XML you parameterize the value to be read from the property:

```
<passwordNode>${#TestCase#passwordVar}</passwordNode>
```

The only catch is that you will have to execute the Groovy step before the SOAP request step, but that can be done at test case level, or in a loop in Groovy, depending on your project structure. I usually have a Groovy script that:

- does calculations or SQL to get input values
- sets properties
- calls the SOAP steps
- extract required response values from resp XML

in a loop.